# Conditional Probability Question with Not condition

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm sure I've missed something simple here, but I'm working with a question of the form
$$
P(A | \overline{B}) 
$$
Using the conditional law, this becomes
$$
P(A | \overline{B}) = \frac{Pr(A \cap \overline{B})}{P(\overline{B})}
$$
Here is the step that I'm unsure of. Here I thought I could apply the compliment law to the denominator and numerator, ie.

$$
P(A | \overline{B}) = \frac{1 - Pr(A \cap B)}{1 - P(B)}
$$
Is this correct? When I apply it to a contingency table of data I'm working with, it yields the wrong answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Your conditional law is wrong.

Comment: @callculus42 sorry, meant to type intersect. I will adjust

Comment: The denominator is alright. The numerator will be $P(A) - P(A \cap B)$

Comment: @QED Thanks, so the law is $P(A \cap B) + Pr(A \cap \overline{B}) = Pr(A)$ ??

Comment: @David exactly.

Comment: @David It is not right that $ {Pr(A \cap \overline{B})}+{Pr(A \cap B)}  =1$. Have a look at the contingency table.

Comment: @callculus42 - Oh absolutely! I was just puzzled as to whether we could directly apply the compliment law to a joint probability

Comment: @QED - Thank you. Please post as an Answer and I will mark it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any two events $A$ and $B$, which are subsets of the population space $\Omega$,we have:
$$\Pr[A] = \Pr[A \cap B] + \Pr[A \cap \overline{B}]$$
If we take $A = \Omega$ in the above equation we get $1 = \Pr[B] + \Pr[\overline{B}]$.
Hence $$\Pr[A | \overline{B}] =  \frac{\Pr[A \cap \overline{B}]}{\Pr[\overline{B}]} = \frac{\Pr[A] - \Pr[A \cap B]}{1 - \Pr[B]}$$